# Maximum function nesting level laravel 5 blade multilevel nesting

Tags: laravel, templates, nested, laravel-blade, extends

I need your help because I have this error when I try to extends a template which extends another one.

```
 Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

> writer/dashboard.blade.php

```html
@extends('user.dashboard')
    @section('writer-dashboard')

        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>Calendrier</a></li>
       
    @endsection
```

> user/dashboard.blade.php
>
> ```html
> @extends('layouts.app')
>    
>     @section('content')
>         <div class="row dashboard">
>             <aside class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 content-box-large">
>                 <ul class="nav">
>                     
>                     
>                         <li class="current"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profil</a></li>
>                         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>Cours</a></li>
>                         @yield('writer-dashboard')
>                    
>                             
>                     </ul>
>                 
>             </aside>
>
>
>     @endsection
> ```
>
> layouts/app.blade.php
>
> ```html
> <!doctype html>
> <html lang="fr">
>     <head>
>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>      
>         @yield('content')
>        
>       
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating infinite loop. Check:

In `dashboard.blade.php` you yield for `writer-dashboard` template. That template call again dashboard and dashboard call again writer-dashboard.

Instead of `@yield` directive, use `@include`. Look for [**Including Sub-Views** in Control Structures' section.](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#control-structures)

Comment: Is it imposible to extends a view which extends another one ?

Because I wanted to do something like:

->User render user.dashboard
->Writer render writer.dashboard inside user.dashboard